# Understand interfaces

Tags: typescript, interface, recursive-type

I don't understand this code:

```
export interface MyType {
  [propertyName: string]: string | MyType;
}
```

I understand that types in a global way serve a function to generalize its use with the business objects of our applications. Types allow to capture the type the user provides in the function.

But in the above code I don't understand:

- the usefulness of the syntax with brackets for the property;
- the fact that the interface has a property whose value is the interface itself. Are interfaces recursive?

Comment: Yes it's recursive. It says this is an associative data structure that maps string keys to strings or other maps that map to strings or...

Answer (score 1):

It is typescript not angular first

```
export interface MyType {
  [propertyName: string]: string | MyType;
}
```

And I think this is better use key

```
interface MyType {
  [key: string]: string | MyType;
}
```

in your example [] is used for key that can be string only. It can't be

```
let x : MyType = {1:"sss"}
```

Key should be string only like

```
let x : MyType = {"1":"sss"}
```

Answer **The fact that the interface has a property whose value is the interface itself. Are the interfaces recursives**

Yes they are

Answer (score 1):

The `[propertyName:string]` means this interface can have zero or multiple keys, like a map. Why the value could be again the same data type could be if you want to represent some child items or binary trees. Here is a example how this interface could be used:

```
interface MyType {
  [propertyName: string]: string | MyType;
}

const a : MyType = {foo: 'bar'}
const b : MyType = {key1: a, key2: 'bar', key3: 'three'}
const c : MyType = {a, b}

const bar: MyType = {
    a,
    b,
    c,
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8Aq6AOKDeAUMsgNo5QD2eUY6AcnALYQBcyAzmFKAOYC67LjxC9kAHzRZcEANyEAvoUIJKILsjjJ2GbHmQBeZPhiVK7AOQAjOFAtLV6sMivapelEfwBrCOgCM7HAANMi%206ABMljZ2oeEAzJZgABZQEBD2KmoaCG66MobGIS5KWU4utjrS%20l7EJJrBdSRWjfXICI1KQA)